# reinstall every gem for each ruby version?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I just installed Ruby 2.0.0 using rbenv and set it to the global ruby version for my system. Since 2.0 is compatible with 1.9.3, I tried to start up a Rails project with it, but got the following error. I did `rbenv rehash` after installing 2.0

```
The `rails' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  1.9.3-p327
```

Does this mean that every gem I installed on my system with 1.9.3 has to be reinstalled if I wish to use it with 2.0?

Comment: In principle yes, but I'd be interested to know if there's an alternative to this that allows us to keep our installed gems.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes.  Rbenv (and RVM) have separate "gem home" directories for each installed version of Ruby.  There may be ways to symlink certain directories to get them to share, but this will likely lead to problems, particularly with gems that include native C extensions, which may or may not compile and run cleanly in multiple versions.

If you have a Gemfile, easiest thing is to just `bundle install` again for Ruby 2.0, giving you duplicate copies of many gems and Ruby-2.0 compiled versions of any native gems.

Answer (score 50):

As seen [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/285):

You need to reinstall bundler for each version of Ruby you use. See Ruby versions where you have it installed:

```
rbenv whence bundle
```

See your current version:

```
rbenv version
```

Install bundler for that version, if missing:

```
gem install bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this is to copy (or reinstall) the gems from your previous version to the newly installed version. How to do that is answered in detail in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649241/copying-gems-from-previous-version-of-ruby-in-rbenv/38250444#38250444), which has two scripts -- one to [install from local cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14616511/4417766), one to [reinstall from the internet](https://gist.github.com/purp/0f96a9689ad0cf92fc24ee5bd90f0b47) (mine).