# Jekyll stack level too deep error when generating site

Tags: jekyll

After a recent Jekyll update I am unable to generate by site and get the error shown below. As a ruby noob I don't know how to go about debugging this further. Does anyone have and suggestions for what could be wrong?

```
jekyll serve -w
Configuration file: /Users/XXXXXXX/workspace/XXXXXXX/_config.yml
Source: /Users/XXXXXXX/workspace/XXXXXXX
Destination: /Users/XXXXXXX/workspace/XXXXXXX/_site
Generating...
/Users/XXXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14: 
      stack level too deep (SystemStackError)


jekyll --version
jekyll 2.1.0

ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to investigate this problem :

1 - Your update is not complete : ruby is updated but not gems. This [aswer can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15327406/1548376)

2 - Your problem comes from a home made jekyll plugin. Then disable all your Jekyll plugins and enable them one at a time to see which one is in error.